# Error while wrting in a text file with pascal

Tags: text, runtime-error, pascal

I'm trying to write a procedure that creates and updates Inventory, however  every time i try to run the program, i get a runtime error and the program closes itself, and it doens't seem to create any text file, i'm not sure what the problem might be or how to solve it, so help would be very much apreciated.

Here is the procedure

```
procedure inventary(arch:string);
var f:text;
    op:char;
    key,name,desc:string;
begin
     assign (f,arch);

     if eof(f) then
        rewrite(f)
         else
      append(f);
                 writeln('Article key');
                 readln(key);
                 writeln('Article name');
                 readln(name);
                 writeln('article description');
                 readln(desc);
                 write(f,key,',',name,',',desc,',');
                 op:='s';
           while (op <> 'n') or (op <> 'N') do
            begin
                 writeln('add another product? y/n');
                 readln(op);
                 if (op = 'y') or (op = 'Y') then
                 begin
                  writeln('Article key');
                 readln(key);
                 writeln('Article name');
                 readln(name);
                 writeln('article description');
                 readln(desc);
                 write(f,key,',',name,',',desc,',');
                 end
                 else
                 writeln('bye');
                 readln();

            end;

close(f);
readln();
end;
```

Program i'm using to test it:

```
  uses proyectounit;
    var
    arch:string;
    c:char;
    begin
    writeln('Name of the inventary');
    readln(arch);
    Writeln('Do you wish to add a product');
    readln(c);
    if c='s' then
    inventary(arch+'.txt');
    Writeln('Do you wish to change something?');
    readln(c);
    if c='s' then
    cambios(arch+'.txt','001');
    writeln('end');
    readln;
    end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `eof` function in this way, it works for open files only. From the help: *Eof(F) tests whether the current file position is the end-of-file. F is a file variable that has been opened for reading.*

If you are using Delphi you can test the existence of a file with  `function FileExists(const FileName: string):Boolean;`, otherwise you should try `append` and if this fails do the `rewrite`

Comment: +1 for fileexists. It should be used, and not the old TP ways. IIRC even the later TP's had a fileexists in TV somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

That might be derived from the classic TP way to check for the existence of a file (afaik still works in [Delphi](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_IOResult.html) and FPC)

```
   assign(f,name); // or assignfile in Delphi 
   {$I-}
    reset(f);
   {$I+}
   if ioresult=0 then
      begin
       /// open succesful
```

but in general, unless you are into archaeology, fileexists() is better.